# Configuring cronjob in wordpress installation (siteground)

Tags: wordpress, cron-job

I'm working on **my first installation of civicrm** (with wordpress) ever and I have a trouble configuring the cronjob. My host is on Siteground and I wolud like to create the cronjob from cPanel.

Before adding the command in cPanel, I've logged in via ssh. [By following a previous thread](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/scheduled-cron-jobs-not-running), I've figured out to write this line:

`/usr/local/bin/php public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php`

But it throughts this **Fatal error**:

`Fatal error: Class 'CRM_Core_Page_Basic' not found in /home/amicsdel/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Job.php on line 37`

Any idea about how to solve it? Where this class is suposed to be declared?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you,

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod

You can follow either of the methods mentioned on that page, depending on how your server is set up.

HTH,
Edsel

Comment: Hi Edsel! Thanks, I revisited the wiki and now I figured out how to ensemble the command! `/usr/local/bin/php ~/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s SITE -u USER -p PASSWORD -e Job -a execute`!

Comment: Yep, that should do it :)